# Help with capturing pause/resume with VideoView with MediaController after video starts

Tags: android

...

```
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        mVideoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        mHeadline = intent.getStringExtra("headline");
        String liveVideoUrl = intent.getStringExtra("live_video_url");
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(liveVideoUrl);
        mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
        mVideoView.start();
```

...

I need to capture when the user presses the pause/play buttons. The VideoView encapsulates Media Player hence how do I capture the play/pause events? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that extends `VideoView` and use this class in your layout which is assigned to `mVideoView`.